# Navbar button spacing is under each other instead of side-by-side

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with my Navbar button spacing. I have no clue why the letters are under each other instead of side-by-side, I have tried using inline-block; but that did not seem to work, so I'm sure there is something happening here in the code that is tripping it out. the sub_menu works fine using inline-block,

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb92hx0k/)

css

```
#right_menu {
  position:fixed;
  font-size:15px;
  top:-80px;
  right:-115px;
  padding:70px;
  background-color:#FF00FF;
  width:-40%;
  height:110%;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

#right_menu > li {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  padding:20px;
  height:16%;
  top:-10px;
  width:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}

#right_menu li a {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  padding:20px;
  position:fixed;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#right_menu > li:hover > a {
  background:#FF00FF;
  top:-1px;
}
```

html

```
<ul id="right_menu"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testing Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testing Three</a>
          <ul class="sub_menu"><li><a href="#">Sub Test</a>
          <ul class="sub_menu2"><li><a href="#">Sub Test Two</a>
        </li>
</ul></li>
          </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Message Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try the `white-space: nowrap;`

```
#right_menu li a {
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 padding: 20px;
 position: fixed;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/sb92hx0k/1/

Comment: Thanks. appreciate it, also could you give a thumbs up on mine as well , trying to get to 50 so i can comment on peoples questions to help out.. Have an awesome night

Comment: Done...  I am in India. Just started my day.. :)

Answer (score 2):

figured out the issue, it was in here, i just added width to my right_menu text

```
#right_menu li a {
  text-align:center;
  width:100px;
  display:block;
  padding:0px;
  position:fixed;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```